# 127.0.0.1 does not work, but localhost works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net

What could be the reason that **127.0.0.1** is not working?

`localhost` works fine

In file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

There is a records:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

I am building a **.NET** application with **SOAP**

Project URL `http://localhost:1399/Services`

I will add that if I change Project Url to **127.0.0.1**, it also doesn't work

EDIT:

Note when I try to set another `Project URL`

[image]

Comment: you specify the port even in the 127.0.0.1, ie http://127.0.0.1:1399/Services ?

Comment: @FelicePollano Yes, I'm getting `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.`

Comment: @starNet, so you have a 400, it means the server is reached and 127.0.0.1 does work, but the server refuse to answer. I think maybe there is some issue in the server in order to prevent remote calls, so somewhere is configured to accept call just from "localhost"

Comment: @FelicePollano How should a valid URL be built to be universal?

Comment: @FelicePollano I added a screen with information when I want to change localhost to another address in the configuration

Comment: A) You can't go trying to use someone else's IP address, such as 1.1.1.1. B) Are you using IIS as the web server?

Comment: Try from cmd.exe >Ping localhost and see what is returned.

Comment: Visual Studio tends to use localhost bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html You also need to know how your VS project is configured, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: That sounds more like a VisualStudio error/limitation/requirement than a network/IP addressing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the catalog:

```
.vs\YourApp\config\
```

Edit file **applicationhost.config**

Find the line:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1399:localhost" />
```

Replace it with

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1399:*" />
```

`*` will make it accept everything so you can use a different IP (e.g. in the android emulator it can be `10.0.2.2` or in the browser `127.0.0.1`)